# Sourcing a file in a new tcsh shell and getting the aliases to work

Tags: shell, environment-variables, alias, tcsh

I would like to source a file in a new tcsh shell.

I can run:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tcsh
konsole --close -e tcsh -exec "ls -l;exec tcsh"
```

This will open a new konsole, list all files and keep the shell interactive.

However, when I try:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tcsh
konsole --close -e tcsh -exec "source /tmp/1234.sh;exec tcsh"
```

I get all the env variables but not the aliases.

For example:
In /tmp/1234.sh: I have:

```
...
setenv MAYA "/maya/path";
alias may 'source /X/tools/binlinux/myscript.tcsh getDirectory ${MAYA} \!*';
...
```

Now in my new shell:

```
$env | grep 'MAYA'
```

will output the correct "MAYA" environment
but:

```
$may
```

may: Command not found.

All the aliases don't work

If I execute:

```
$source /tmp/1234.sh
```

in the new shell, then all aliases will work fine.

Please note that I am unable to store data in any file such as .tchrc or change the format of the /tmp/1234.sh file.

How can I get the aliases to work in the new shell?

Comment: I am using Linux Centos 6

Answer (score 0):

`exec` replaces the current process with a new one. The `source` command is run in the old process, and the new process doesn't inherit the state of that (except for environment variables).

The easiest way to do what you want is to set an environment variable, and change the behaviour on that in your tcshrc file; e.g.:

```
#!/bin/sh
export FOO=bar
konsole --close -e tcsh
```

And then in your tcshrc pick up on that:

```
if ( $?FOO ) then
    setenv MAYA "/maya/path";
    alias may 'source /X/tools/binlinux/myscript.tcsh getDirectory ${MAYA} \!*';
endif
```

There is no real way to tell tcsh to read the configuration from another location. I once sent in a patch for this but that was rejected.

Comment: Thank you for your elegant solution. The problem is that I am unable to edit the .tcshrc file. The reason is that the /tmp/1234.sh file is generated by studio script. Every time the studio script takes different input, it generates a different  /tmp/1234.sh file. The studio script is used by many users and I will not be able to create a script that modifies their .tchrc files.

Comment: Can we modify:                                                                                                       
alias may 'source /X/tools/binlinux/myscript.tcsh getDirectory ${MAYA} \!*';               in a script so that it gets sourced?

Comment: Note there is a system-wide `/etc/csh.cshrc` file that is read for *all* users @AlIbrahim, you can put it in there. You can also pass the filename as an environment variable.

Comment: Thank you very much. It did work using my .tcshrc file. I am getting our system admins to add it to the /etc/csh.cshrc file.

Comment: Is there is another way to do so without changing .tcshrc or /etc/csh.cshrc? I am unable to change these files for all users.